# jquery conflict in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I saw on the internet so many solution but i don't get it. Can someone help me out with this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter.js"></script>
<script id="data" type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js" xmlData="data/raetexport.xml"></script>
```

How do i fix the jquery problem because i have a wordpress theme that is already using jquery. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: If your theme is already loading jquery , why are you doing it again.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use $ for jquery in your search.js, if so you could try wrapping the entire file in `({})(jQuery);`. If that didn't fix it maybe you should post the contents of the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put like this :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script id="data" type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js" xmlData="data/raetexport.xml"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tablesorter.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When i remove this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://aagjemobiel.wsg.nu/Search/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

My dropdown from my theme works but then my search button won't work. So i have a conflict with jquery.